# Outlook 2007 receives html mail as source with headers, others MUAs work fine. Why?

Tags: php, outlook, html-email

I have a couple of simple forms that send an html-only email. Most clients (Gmail, Lotus Notes 8, hotmail/live, windows live mail, outlook express) receive the emails just fine, but Outlook 2007 does not.

The code looks like this:

```
$data="
            <html>
                <body>
                    <strong><u>$sub</u></strong><br><br>
                    <strong>Name:</strong> {$_POST["nombre"]}<br><br>
                    <strong>Phone:</strong>{$_POST["telefono"]}<br><br>
                    <strong>Email:</strong> {$_POST["email"]}<br><br>
            <strong>Subject:</strong> {$_POST["asunto"]}<br><br>
                    <strong>Question:</strong> {$_POST["consulta"]}</strong>
                </body>
            </html>";
            $header = "Reply-To: $from\r\n";
            $header .= "From: \"".$_POST["nombre"]."\" <$from>\r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

            $enviado = mail($destino,$sub,$data,$header);
```

(`$from` is the only part of the message validated)

The message received by the customer looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
From: Consulta de "Boss" <boss@myfirm.com>
Reply-To: boss@myfirm.com
X-Mailer: PHP/

<strong><u>Solicitud de envío de recetas -
CLIENT</u></strong><br><br><strong>Nombre y Apellido:</strong>
Boss<br><br><strong>Email:</strong>
boss@myfirm.com<br><br><br>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried sending multipart email, when doing this we never had issues with outlook 2k3 and 2k7 (excepts poor HTML rendering)

```
<?php
$header = "From: Sender <sen...@domain.org>\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-to: Sender <blabla...@domain.net>\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: Our Php\r\n";

$boundary = "==String_Boundary_x" .md5(time()). "x\r\n";
$boundary2 = "==String_Boundary2_y" .md5(time()). "y\r\n";

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/related;\r\n";
$header .= " type="multipart/alternative";\r\n";
$header .= " boundary="$boundary";\r\n";

$message = "If you read this, your email client doesn't support MIME\r\n";

$message .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\r\n";
$message .= " boundary="$boundary2";\r\n";

$message .= "--$boundary2\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "Alternative message in plain text format.\r\n";

$message .= "--$boundary2\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "<html><body><p>HTML formatted message</p></body></html>";
```

You can replace boundaries with whatever you want, but they must be unique.

For more powerful and flexible email sending in php I suggest to use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

EDIT : as Outlook 2007 has a really dumb HTML renderer, you can also try fixing your markup, there is a `</font>` never opened in your example, dunno if it's the real mail or a typo in question.

Comment: Who downvoted on this ? please can you explain why ? did I made a mistake or misinformation ?

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem,  try removing the /r from your returns and use only /n.  Outlook andd hotmail have trouble with /r/n.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm the experience with Exchange *janmoesen* has shared.
Had to change CRLF in headers to just LF, then it started working.

(Thank you Microsoft, once again, for having me work 40% time extra.

Also a real thank you to janmoesen for pointing this! This search is over.)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with Outlook 2007.

The answer is simple : replace **\r\n** by **\n**

Answer (score 2):

I have had trouble with Exchange (not just Outlook) and CRLF in headers with similar results. Basically, we were sending mails (using PHP on Debian with Postfix) with CRLF-separated headers, which would get mangled in Exchange upon arrival. When I changed those `\r\n` to simply `\n`, the problem was gone. ("RFCs be damned!", eh?)

YMMV, obviously, since it is not clear whether your other mail clients connect to the same server as Outlook, or use separate servers altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If the message is in HTML you need to identify it as such:

```
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Comment: Argh! copied and pasted from the wrong version (I was editing the code to plaintext to get by). It did say 'text/html' in the real code. I corrected the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have always had better luck with MIME encoded HTML mails.  Even if there is just one part, I typically use multipart/mixed and explicitly set the content type (text/html).  I'm not very familiar with PHP, but the `PEAR::Mail_Mime` package looks like a candidate.

- http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime

Outlook shouldn't have a problem handling it.  (emphisis on **shouldn't**).

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of problems with HTML email in Outlook 2007.
http://www.molly.com/2007/01/18/what-happened-with-html-and-css-in-outlook-2007/

http://fixoutlook.org/

http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/html/microsoft-complicates-html-emails-with-outlook-2007-070130/page1.html

and so on.

Comment: Ok, but those problems are (as far as I read) of the 'my layout is not showing correctly' kind, not of the 'crap, the headers of the message are displayed and I get raw html' kind. Or am I wrong? The layout for the message in question has nothing complicated.

Comment: I imagine it's related. I fought with this a few years back and gave up.  HTML email is evil anyway, and outlook is trying its best to deal with the evils of HTML email by fiddling with your content.

Comment: Oh, sure. I'm phoning the customer right now and telling her 'you know what? HTML email is evil. Justin said so'.

Comment: I'm not frustrated. I'm curious. I want to know why. You're the one that said 'I gave up a few years back'. And your 'html email is evil' point is ridiculous. Leave the term to something truly worthy of it. Like Cobol.

Comment: Look, I'm not trying to get into an argument here, I'm just stating what I believe to be true.  I'm not the one who decided HTML email is a bad idea.  There's information all over the web that says the same thing, if you care to do a bit of googling.  It's one of those user-friendly "features" that turned out to be a huge security nightmare, and there are reasons that MS Outlook doesn't just display HTML email as-is.

Comment: please, reread the question and my first comment to this answer.

Comment: Outlook using MS Word to render HTML formatted email won't be the problem here. The problem here is extracting the message body from the email, which has nothing to do with what happens to the body afterwards.