# HTML email formatting

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mail() header problem for html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850701/mail-header-problem-for-html-email)

I'm using the following for `$headers`:

```
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: " .  $from . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: me@site.com\r\n";
```

My `html` looks fine in Gmail, however, it appears as raw `html` in outlook.

Did I forget something in the header?

Comment: is your outlook allowed to display html? corporates sometimes disable it and dont notice due to outlooks own rich text formatting being good enough

Comment: You should use a Mail class like SwiftMailer.

Comment: @Louis - Yes, I can receive HTML

Comment: @binarious - I really don't want to add a class. This is simply a notification email getting sent when a user registers.

Comment: What's wrong with one of the many pre-built libraries that does this?

Comment: @Paul maybe check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149366/outlook-2007-receives-html-mail-as-source-with-headers-others-muas-work-fine-w

Comment: Check out this solution to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2423592/1012061

Comment: @Incognito Nothing wrong - it just seems like overkill for a simple task PHP can handle

Comment: Might want to take a read.... http://www.heavyworks.net/blog/posts/quick-tip-php-mail-header-misuse-vulnerability

Comment: @ShawnH. - Thanks Shawn! That solved my problem. If you submit an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the question located here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423592/1012061 as @Shawn H. recommended in the comments above.

One of the answers says this:

"I had a very similar problem, try removing the /r from your returns and use only /n. Outlook andd hotmail have trouble with /r/n."

That worked great!

Answer (score 0):

In outlook 2007 (at least). It is possible to change the email-format. Have a look at: Tools > Options > E-Mail-Format (tab) > Messageformat (select box) > change to html

Hope that helps.